# Does every class extend Object?

Tags: java, inheritance

I read that every class extends a object class by default. Then it should cause multiple inheritance and must not be supported by Java.

Comment: Yes... But multiple inheritance is **not** this

Comment: Not every class _directly_ extends `Object`.  Given `class A extends Object` and `class B extends A`, `A` directly extends `Object`, `B` directly extends `A`, and `B` indirectly extends `Object` though `A`.  You'd only have a diamond problem if `B` extended `Object` through two different paths.  That a class has multiple superclasses doesn't necessarily mean you have multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 22):

When you have something like

```
class A {}
```

then `A` implicitly extends `Object`. In fact the bytecode resembles

```
class A extends Object {}
```

Now, if we have

```
class B extends A {}
```

Then `B` extends `A` but is *also* a subclass of `Object`, since `A` is a subclass of `Object`. This is not, however, multiple inheritance:

```
Object
  |
  A
  |
  B
```

Multiple inheritance would look like this:

```
Object   A
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
     B
```

i.e. `B` inheriting from two hierarchically unrelated classes.

Comment: We said `public class A{}` implicitly extends `Object`, so it is equal to `public class A extends Object`. And when we have `public class B extends A`, because if only `public class B`, it equals to `public class B extends Object`, so now `public class B extends A` equals to `public class B extends A, Object`. So maybe this is why someone confuse this question.

Comment: Right. In a nutshell, implicit extension will only happen when no explicit `extends` is provided.

Answer (score 5):

How can it be multiple inheritance?

```
class Object { /* stuff */ }

class Foo /* implicit extends Object */ {}

class FooBar extends Foo /* and therefore extends Object */ {}
```

[The rules are described in the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2):

> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

Comment: How compiler came to know.can any body tell me how compiler works here?

Comment: @user2848012 How does compiler know what? The rules are specified in the Java language specification. For a compiler to be compatible with Java, it needs to follow those rules.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion seems to be in the meaning of the term "Multiple Inheritance." Multiple inheritance refers to when an object can be a DIRECT descendant of more than one other type.

This would be an example of multiple inheritance, and is not supported in Java:

```
class Z extends A, B, C{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at a class, for example `A`, looking up the inheritance tree will always return you to `Object`. If there are multiple classes between `A` and `Object`, this is not multiple inheritance. This can be drawn like so:

```
Object
|
SomeIntermediateClass
|
A
```

Multiple inheritance occurs when a single class is the child of at least two "branches" in an inheritance tree. For example:

```
Object
|   |
A   B
 \ /
  C
```

In the above case, `C` is inheriting from multiple parents, and is thus involved in multiple-inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.
>   [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance means that a class inherits from multiple classes that are not in the same line of inheritance.  The problem with multiple inheritance is that if methods and instance variables have the same name but different operations or values, it is not clear which inherited method or variable is the one to use.

For example:

```
class Foo {
    void baz() { }
}
class Bar {
    void baz() { System.out.println("test"); }
}
class FooBar extends Foo extends Bar {}
```

is an example of multiple inheritance.  If an object of class FooBar called baz(), we would not know which baz() to use.

However, it is not multiple inheritance if class FooBar only extends class Foo, but not class Bar (and class Foo extends class Object).  If a method in Object, such as toString() were to be written in Foo, such a method would override Object's toString() i.e. class FooBar would know that the child class, Foo's toString() should be called and not the parent class, Object's toString().